# $f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}}$ Laurent series in $z=i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

How to find the Laurent series of the following function in $z=i$.

$$f(z)=e^{\frac{1}{(z+i)(z-i)}}$$

I know that it is a essential singularity. There is a way to find the series rapresention without calculate the following integral for every single term

$$\sum a_{k}(z-z_{0})^{k}$$

$$a_{k}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma } \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_{0})^{k+1}}dz$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your absolutely correct that the series expansion can be obtained using Cauchy's integral formula.

But there is an easier way.

Hint 1: Use the series expansion for exponential functions:
$$ \exp \left( \frac 1 {(z + i)(z - i)}\right) = 1 + \frac 1 {(z + i)(z - i)} + \frac 1 {2!} \times \frac 1 { (z + i)^2(z - i)^2} + \dots $$

Hint 2: Use partial fractions:
$$ \frac 1 {(z + i)(z - i)} = \frac i {2(z + i)} - \frac i {2(z - i)}$$

Hint 3: Use the geometric series formula to expand $1/(z + i)$ around $z = i$:
\begin{align*} \frac 1 {z + i}  & =  \frac 1 {2i + (z-i)}  \\\
&  =  (2i)^{-1} \times \frac 1 {1 + (2i)^{-1}(z-i)} \\\ & =  (2i)^{-1} \times \left(1 - (2i)^{-1}(z-i) + (2i)^{-2}(z-i)^{2} - (2i)^{-3}(z-i)^{3} + \dots \right)\end{align*}
which converges for $| z - i | < 2$.